# amCharts: Open a URL when Clicking Map Marker

Tags: amcharts

I'm using the [amCharts "Capitals map" demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/capitals-map/) ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/szwfgk4n/)) as a starting point for a project. I would like to be able to click or touch on the marker for a capital and open a URL.

In some situations, it appears this functionality works out of the box by adding a URL parameter, for example:

```
{
    "title": "Washington, D.C.",
    "latitude": 38.8921,
    "longitude": -77.0241,
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C."
}
```

I'm hoping to be able to click on Washington D.C. and open that link to Wikipedia, however, nothing happens. I imagine it's a simple oversight - what additional changes need to be made to that demo in order to get a link/URL to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track.

Right now you're providing `url` as a data field, just as you are for `latitude` and `longitude`. So, it's just data, the chart doesn't make any assumptions what to do with it asides from becoming available as a [placeholder for strings](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/#Data_placeholders). To bind or apply the `url` from your data to the `MapImage`'s [`url` property](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mapimage/#url_property), use the [property binding notation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Property_fields). In the original demo you'll find that is what's done for the `latitude` and `longitude` fields:

```js
imageSeriesTemplate.propertyFields.latitude = "latitude";
imageSeriesTemplate.propertyFields.longitude = "longitude";
```

Now we just have to do that for `url`:

```js
imageSeriesTemplate.propertyFields.url = "url";
```

With that in place, any `MapImage` with an `url` in its data will become a clickable link that takes you to said `url`. By default it'll open in the same window. To change the link target just update its [`urlTarget` property](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mapimage/#urlTarget_property), e.g.:

```js
imageSeriesTemplate.urlTarget = "_blank";
```

Here's a fork of the jsfiddle with the above additions:

http://jsfiddle.net/notacouch/szwfgk4n/3/

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick, thorough, well-written answer that solves the issue.

Comment: @NickBenson You're welcome! I feel compelled to clarify that I actually work for amCharts. But it's definitely my pleasure to be of service.